# what does mono returns code 249 means?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, mono, libc

I'm using mono, and my executable is exiting normally.

However doing `echo $?` after the execution, I get 249.

I cannot find a list of mono return code, is there a place to find it?

Comment: That should mean that your application is exiting with an exit code of 249. Are you sure that isn't happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your application exits with the [`-7`](http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Errors/unix_system_errors.html) error code. The number is negative because `libc` appends the minus sign to all error codes returned by the kernel syscalls (which are [positive](http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Errors/unix_system_errors.html) integers). Eventually, `bash` converts `-7` to `249` through `$?`.

*test.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash
exit -7
```

*Calling `test.sh`*

```
bash test.sh
$?
249
```

Comment: Then wouldn't the exec be not running? Because it runs perfectly fine, does what it is supposed to

Comment: Yes. I believe it shouldn't start if the arguments are wrong. Still, check the exact version of the `libc` library used by your application, because e.g. [here](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/libc/libc_293.html) you can find a different set of error codes.

Answer (score 1):

**Mono Return Codes:**

0 or -1 (255 in posix) for Main Entry points of void type

- Note: If the return type of Main is void, -1 is only set the exitcode if an un-handled exception was thrown

Any int value for Main Entry points of int type

- Posix/Bash will box that to 0-255 due to historical exit code (lower 8 bits) and status (upper 8 bits) (unless you are running a posix 2001 system ;-)
- Full int values can be optained by exec'ing (system/fork/spawn/etc...)

Again, -1 is 'reserved' for exception based exits...

Based on the entry point having a std MONO_TYPE_I4 (0x08) return signature:

```
        MonoObject *res;
        res = mono_runtime_invoke (method, NULL, pa, exc);
        if (!exc || !*exc)
                rval = *(guint32 *)((char *)res + sizeof (MonoObject));
        else
                rval = -1;
        mono_environment_exitcode_set (rval);
```

And assuming you do not have your program running and corrected to a debugger and are not setting the exit code yourself, getting a exit code of 249/-7 means a non-standard exit and based in the limited exit points and the areas that can the exit code, I'd look for a thread you are not cleaning up (i.e. a managed thread becomes a 'native' pthread on OS-X or a __thread on Linux or ....) or some other managed to native/interop process hanging open (GPU, filesystem operation, etc...).

You can always run your app "MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug mono someapp.exe" and lookup at the shutdown/exit trace.